# accessing s3 from lambda within VPC in aws-go-sdk

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc

I'm just started on using aws-sdk-go and notice that the s3 requests are using http/https rather than s3 protocol. How can I read the object in s3 from my lambda within vpc using aws-sdk-go?

And I don't want to use NAT Gateway. I can do this in NodeJS but is there any way for aws-go-sdk to do the same?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no "S3 protocol."  S3 uses HTTP.  The `s3://bucket/object` notation (if this is what you are referring to) is simply a URI format, a notational style.  It's not clear what you are saying you can do in Node that is different than Go... please clarify this, because there should be no difference.

Comment: ah.. I thought s3:// and https:// are different

Comment: yeah.. It turns out that I need the S3 Endpoint as mentioned by @Robo. Sorry for the confusion. The application in NodeJS belongs to a VPC that does have an s3 endpoint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access S3 within a VPC without an internet gateway you need to use a [S3 Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-endpoints-s3.html)

Answer (score 3):

This code snippet shows how to use aws-go-sdk to list S3 buckets for region us-east-1 within a Lambda function:

```
func listBuckets() {
    svc := s3.New(session.New(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String("us-east-1")}))
    buckets, err := svc.ListBuckets(nil)
    log.Printf("listBuckets: %q error=%v", buckets, err)
}
```

Find full source code here: https://github.com/udhos/hellolambda/blob/master/main.go