# AWS VPC API access via VPC Interface Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-vpc

I need to create an AWS Lambda that uses the AWS SDK, and communicates through a [VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html), in order to dynamically adjust routes found in a VPC route table.  The problem is that the [VPC Endpoint list of supported services](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) does not list "VPC API" (though it does mention EC2 API).  Does this mean my goal simply isn't possible through a `VPC Endpoint`, or am I interpreting the documentation too strictly?

Also, to be clear, I'm expressly avoiding a NAT Gateway / IGW.  This is why my question centers on `VPC Endpoints`.

Incidentally, here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49809623/accessing-s3-from-lambda-within-vpc-in-aws-go-sdk).

Comment: Amazon VPC is managed through the Amazon EC2 endpoint. Have you attempted to make VPC API calls via an EC2 Endpoint? I haven't tried it, so I can't say that it would definitely work. Please let us know what you find!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [the AWS CLI functions for VPC configuration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/search.html?q=vpc&check_keywords=yes&area=default).  VPC is a basic component in AWS, and should not have any gaps in feature configuration.

Comment: If you are merely saying that the AWS CLI is capable of manipulating VPC configuration, then I agree.  But the problem is that I'm trying to do that manipulation *through a VPC endpoint*.  If the `VPC endpoint` does not allow access to the VPC API, then it doesn't matter that the AWS CLI/SDK does allow access.  In short, this question is far more about networking via a `VPC Endpoint` than it is about the AWS CLI/SDK.

Comment: Right, but somewhere on the other side of that VPC, there has to be an EC2 instance, lambda, or other that can exec compute load.  The same compute can be given access to KMS where a credential is stored, that grant privs to run the AWS CLI for VPC.  Or does you scenario inhibit that?